# SQL Cast in select based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, casting, numeric

Is there a way to cast an nvarchar field in the select statement based on whether or not it is numeric or not.  I currently have this code but it is trying to convert one of the non numeric values for some reason.

```
  SELECT id,
  CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(field) = 1 THEN CAST(field AS INT) ELSE CAST(field AS NVARCHAR(10)) END AS [fieldName]
  FROM table1
```

Comment: A column in SQL has a datatype.  You couldn't mix datatypes in the same column.  Maybe what you can do is to use a SQL_VARIANT column (Just thinking)

Comment: The answer, regrettably, is no.  Your query returns a single column, which has a single data type.  Asking SQL Server to return two different data types for a single column is like asking for a four-wheel drive motorcycle.

Comment: There are alternatives, such as converting a value to a number in a specific format, then converting it back to an nvarchar value - can you describe what it is that you're trying to accomplish here? Maybe there's another way we could approach the problem.

Comment: I am putting the values into a datagridview in VB and want it to sort the numbers correctly, ascending or descending, when clicking column header of datagridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it sort correctly if you pad the left of the numeric values with zeroes, as in the following?

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Field NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field) VALUES (10)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field) VALUES (100)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Field) VALUES ('abv')

SELECT 
    Field,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1 
        THEN RIGHT('000000000' + Field,10) 
        ELSE Field 
     END AS SortField
FROM @Table1
ORDER BY SortField DESC

SELECT 
    Field,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(Field) = 1 
        THEN RIGHT('000000000' + Field,10) 
        ELSE Field 
     END AS SortField
FROM @Table1
ORDER BY SortField ASC
```

Comment: works but looks messy in datagridview.  is there anyway to hide some of the zeros to show just the last 34 characters?

Comment: You can set the length using the `RIGHT('000000000' + Field,10)` section - change the number of zeroes to whatever you need, and the 10 to the number you want.

Comment: That worked thanks!  Just curious, how does padding 0's sort the strings as though they were ints?

Comment: Sorting text is different than sorting numbers ... text starts with the first character, then goes to the second, etc.  So, since a 1 is lower than a 2, anything with a 1 is going to come before a 2, regardless of how many zeroes come after it.  (e.g., 1, 1000, 2).  This works the same way as a text value; if you see azzzzzzz, it is always going to come before b.  However, if the first character is a zero, that obviously comes before one, so it buckets it appropriately (e.g., 0001, 0002, 1000).